# How to close with the back button when a dialog is active on jQuery mobile

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am creating an Android App UI with PhoneGap and jQuery moble. Although the dialog of jQuery mobile was displayed on HTML, when the back key of the device is pressed, this application will be exited. I would like to close not an application but its dialog. What should I program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen to `backbutton` event and act accordingly. Something like this should work:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function() {
  $('your_dialog_element').dialog('close');
}, false);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using routing on my web. So if I press backspace it goes to the last page. What would you do? (I'm using react-router-v4)